# Status of the "minor tractates"

Tags: talmud-gemara

Why were the so-called "minor tractates" (מסכתות קטנות) not incorporated into the Talmud?  Are they any less authoritative?  Haven't we extracted halacha from them?  They certainly deal with very practical matters (conversion, mezuzah, tefillin, tzitzit, etc.)

Comment: Are they not in the Talmud? They're present in all my copies

Comment: Not mine.  Schottenstein doesn't have them.  I asked Artscroll but they said they have no plan to publish them.  Soncino has a translation.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi they're in the Vilna Shas, which artscroll is a translation of. Are you asking why artscroll doesn't want to translate them?

Comment: @robev -- The "minor tractates" were never canonized and are hardly ever cited, except maybe for ARN.  I am asking...  see my question.

Comment: What do you mean canonized and what is ARN

Comment: (1) Officially accepted as part of the Talmud. See https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/minor-tractates . (2) Avot d'Rabbi Natan.